# If I leave a Minecraft Realm will my signs disappear or still be there?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I wrote some notes on sign, if I leave that Minecraft Realm will my signs disappear or still be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this one below is the sign you're referring to, everything you wrote on them, when correctly placed, will remain after you log out.

[image]

If your signs disappear while you leave they are simply broken by someone else.

Comment: it is, yes. thank you :)